# What is the politically correct replacement of the adjectives "female" and "male" with regard to trans* people's bodies?

Tags: grammatical-gender, gender-neutral, political-correctness, gender-politics

I've just discovered this little forum, so I shall be giving it much use as there are lots of thing over which I need to go.

I know that there are some trans* people who are *really* uncomfortable about others' using, or even them using for themselves, binary-based language which reproduces this idea that all human bodies are either "female" or "male" and that everyone is either "female" or "male". This is or can be a dysphoria-inducing experience for them.

This is something I want to wholly bypass if possible as I am a writer and speaker who often speaks and writes about issues of sexual orientation, sex, gender identity, other LGBTQ+ issues, and non-LGBTQ+-related issues, so it is particularly pertinent to me and my situation that this want of mine to find other terms is achievable.

A lot of my research has ended in disaster because most of the language hasn't been too good: for example, there are sentence constructions like "... who has external genitals" which is not always acceptable for me to write for the sake of space when I'm expected to write something with a specific number of words. So are there non-wordy sentence constructions which articulate that someone has a vulva or a penis, for example, without saying "X has a penis"?

Answer (score -1):

This is challenging, indeed. Talking about social roles or blood relations you have options such as:

husband/wife = spouse

brother/sister = sibling

son/daughter = child/kid

etc.

When it comes to choosing the common denominator for *male and female* the only options seem to be: no-sex, pan-sex (this one would be my choice), every-sex, all-sex, genderless. If you do not intend to outline someone's sex, you still have to remember that some of the transgender do not want to be ascribed to any sex, so *no-sex* might be a choice in this case.

It is difficult to give you a language remedy, for it still depends on the context. Can we talk about *every-sex toilets* or *no-sex toilets*? The first suggests that everyone: male, female and everyone in-between is welcome here; while the second suggests only those who says "no" to any gender can come in…

*Genderless* might be a picklock in most cases but in addressing your words to someone might be too lowkey, e.g.:

*I invite all the genderless to the left side of the room* — this might sound awkward.

So in this case I would say: 
*I invite all the pan-sex to the left side of the room* — but still that leaves some space for misunderstanding (as usual…)

Sometimes it might be situational and it only depends on canny resolving of such a situation. So following the citation from one of the most famous musicals "Kinky Boots", you could say:

"And those who have yet to make up their mind I invite to the left side of the room!" — this seems smart and peppered with humor, but still delays the decision on calling by a tag everyone who does not wish to be tagged.

In your area I think that whatever you will use, it should not be overworked and it should resonate in the (sub?)culture of the group — that's why a citation from "Kinky Boots" seems a good way out.

Maybe ***non-cisgender*** is what you are looking for? It says that the person does not identify with the gender he/she was born with.

Also ***queer*** but that implies some discussion on sexual orientation.

The broadest term, however, would be ***nonconforming***, but that gives a sense of social exclusion.

As I mentioned, the choice strongly depends on the context here.